# TradingView - Pine Editor Error: Could not get Pine source code reason error:

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I tried to open the source code for the built-in "Cyber Ensemble Strategy" Strategy and this strategy is not locked but I got an error saying: Could not get Pine source code. Does anybody know what this means or how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not locked but it is **protected**.

There are three types of visibilities when you publish a script:

### Open

The Pine code of scripts published open is visible to all users.

### Protected

The code of protected scripts is hidden from view and no one but its author can access it. While the script’s code is not accessible, protected scripts can be used freely by any user.

### Invite-only

The invite-only access type protects both the script’s code and its use. The publisher of an invite-only script must explicitly grant access to individual users.

See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Publishing_scripts.html#access) for more information.